# When do we use ANTLR

Tags: c#, antlr

Can anyone please guide me the purpose of using ANTLR dlls in a ASP.Net, C# project.

I just noticed *antlr.runtime*, *Antlr3.Runtime*, *Antlr3.Utlility* assemblies being referenced in some project.

Will be great if can cite some real world examples or any link to a web page will be useful.

Comment: I don't know why and from where but this antlr3 is present in my ASP.NET Web API project. Can I remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need these dll's if you are parsing any text at runtime using an antlr grammar.

Typically there are two steps.

1) run the java antlr parser over your .g files to generate a C# lexer, C# grammar and possibly C# tree walkers.

2) Build those files into your application.  Those files will work in conjunction with the antlr.runtime dll, or antlr3.runtime dll if you're using ANTLR version 3.

Your C# program can now parse text files using the grammar that you compiled in step 1.

Answer (score 54):

The Antlr package is used by the WebGrease package.  The WebGrease package is used by the ASP.NET Web Optimization package.

If you want to remove Antlr, remove the ASP.NET Web Optimization package.  It will in turn remove the other 2 packages.

It does not affect performance much, provided that you designed your application properly.

Answer (score 7):

ANTLR is a parser generator that is able to generate parsers in multiple languages including C#. The ANTLR homepage is [here](http://www.antlr.org/).

The creator Terence Parr has also published a book, [The Definitive ANTLR Reference](http://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr/the-definitive-antlr-reference).

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I still wonder if I need to add reference for it if I create a C# ASP.Net app. Else in what cases do I need to reference ANTLR?

Comment: Are you using ANTLR at all to create a Lexer/Parser? If so you will have a file defining a grammar (probably a ".g" file). If not then you should be able to remove the references to the DLLs.

Answer (score 4):

The [ASP.NET Web Optimization package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/) has a dependency on [WebGrease](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebGrease/) which in turn has a dependency on [Antlr](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr/). If you want to remove [Antlr](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr/) you must remove [ASP.NET Web Optimization](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/). So the question now becomes:

> What is the [ASP.NET Web Optimization package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/) used for in a new MVC project?

It is used to bundle and minify the `.css` and `.js` resources. In a new ASP.NET MVC web project there is a file named `/App_Start/BundleConfig.cs` where the bundles are defined. For example:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css", "~/Content/site.css"));
// etc.
```

In the `/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` these defined bundles are then added to the returned view.

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

So if you remove these references you will have to use a different strategy/tool to bundle/minify your dependencies like gulp with [gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) and [gulp-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify).