# Unable to update auto-refresh reference 'antlr3.runtime.dll'. Cannot find assembly (Asp.net c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have the a warning when I run my asp.net website. It says: "Unable to update auto-refresh reference 'antlr3.runtime.dll'. Cannot find assembly".
Despite the warning, my website is still running well.

I have tried to resolve this warning by going to > Manage NugGet Packages, then I tried searching for the correct antlr3 package to install, but to no avail, the warning still persists.
How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180634/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-antlr3-runtime-1-or-one-of-its-dependencies

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177606/when-do-we-use-antlr) SO question and your package.config file. Try to [restore](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore) your packages. As a last resort remove the entry in package.config and add the package again.

Comment: @JeroenHeier Hi, Where do I find the package.config in my website?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467094/nuget-issues-with-packages-config-project-references-and-the-solutionwide-packa) SO qustion. A NuGet package is located at project (after using the NuGet package manager in Visual Studio) or solution level,